# Are the joints in this concrete path correct?

Tags: concrete

We had a new patio and a sidewalk around the side of the house poured.  Where there is a bend or a corner there is a joint tooled from edge to edge (in green in image).  Most are about 8 feet apart, but one straight run of the path is 20 feet long with no edge to edge joint in it.  This seems mostly correct and as expected.

However, between these edge to edge joints there are additional tool joints that do not go all the way through to the edge (in red in image).  The joint was tooled first, then the edge was tooled which closed the joint on the edges of the path.  See the attached photos.

Are the joints done correctly?  I don't recall ever seeing the joints not go edge to edge, but it seems intentional.  Is it just decorative and not a functional joint?

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You might want to look more closely.

Typically the joint in green would be a full-on **expansion joint** with a filler material between two slabs, and in the better class of walk there will also be sliding-joint pins set in the slabs to tie them together so they can move back and forth without moving up and down and becoming uneven.

The joint in red is a **control joint**, just tooled in the surface, to cause any future cracking to preferentially happen there, in a nice straight line, not just at random. Reenforcement will run through the joint (if the slab is reenforced) and that will prevent significant vertical movement there.

Comment: What's the old saying? "*There are two types of concrete: concrete that has cracked, and concrete that is about to crack.*"?

Comment: Thank you, i did look at it more closely and I have some more information.  

The joint circled in green has no expansion material in it.  It is the same in every respect as the joint circled in red except that it goes edge to edge across the concrete.

The concrete is reinforced with rebar, however i'm unable to say whether or not any "sliding-joint pins" were used.

My main concern is that water will not drain out of the joint in red.

Is this normal for a "control joint"?

Comment: If you're concerned about drainage, get your contractor back out with a concrete saw and tell him to put a groove across the edge.